# sharepoint : custom wiki page layout with forms

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

(rookie question ... just getting started with Sharepoint)

Is it possible to create a custom page layout for a wiki page which contains form elements?

Basically, I want to create a site that will host wiki pages, with associated features like rating, comments etc. But I want the wiki content to be structured somewhat. There need to be form elements like select boxes, radio buttons - and then a free form wiki area that would be composed using the WYSIWYG editor.

How would I go about doing this? Where should I look for documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to implement this is to use a normal wiki page and all your form elements can be implemented as a web part.

With SHarepoint you can use visual webparts which is basically a Custom User control (ascx) wrapped in a webpart container.

The advantage of this is you can then insert your webpart into the rich text editor using the ribbon or if you are using the publishing feature even include it in a custom page layout so it will be there for all the pages that implement that custom layout.

TO know more about visual webparts:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff597539(v=office.14).aspx

Custom Page Layouts:

http://blog.henryong.com/2010/06/08/how-to-create-custom-sharepoint-2010-page-layouts-using-sharepoint-designer-2010/